# How to give every node the same start position on the screen even if the parent is moving?

Tags: swift, xcode, nodes, skspritenode, cgpoint

I´m developing a game with SpriteKit. I have a cube which is the parent for all the other nodes. If the user taps on the screen Node1 starts falling down from the middle of the screen. AfterNode1 lands on the cube, the cube moves down a bit. When the user taps again Node2 starts falling down but Node2 has a lower position then Node1 because the parent moved down.

Is there a way to set the position of every node to a certain point on the screen regardless of where the parent is?

The parent node:

```
Cube.setScale(0.85)
Cube.zPosition = 3
Cube.position.x = self.size.width / 2
Cube.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: CubeTexture,size: CGSize(width: CubeTexture.size().width * 0.9, height: CubeTexture.size().height * 0.82)) 
    Cube.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    Cube.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.addChild(Cube)
```

The child nodes:

```
    node1.setScale(0.95)
    node1.position = CGPoint(x: -350, y: 310)  //<-- I want this position to be a constant value on the screen
    node1.zPosition = 1

    node1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: node1Texture,size: CGSize(width: node1Texture.size().width * 1.1, height: node1Texture.size().height * 0.85)) 
    node1.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    node1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    node1.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    node1.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    Cube.addChild(node1):


    lazy var node2 = node1.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    lazy var node3 = node1.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    lazy var node4 = node1.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    lazy var node5 = node1.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    lazy var node6 = node1.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    lazy var node7 = node1.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    lazy var node8 = node1.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    lazy var node9 = node1.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    lazy var node10 = node1.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
```

Cube movement every time a node falls down:

```
  func addMovement3(Cube:SKSpriteNode) {
    var actionArray = [SKAction]()

    actionArray.append(SKAction.moveTo(y: Cube.position.y - 61.8, duration: 0.1))

    Cube.run(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create or reference the parent of the cube node.  Instead of adding your nodes to the cube, add your nodes as child of the parent of the cube, as the cube moves down the nodes will be able to maintain their origin.

Comment: But it´s essential for the game that the nodes are childs of the cube. Because if the cube moves the childs move with the cube. If the nodes weren't childs of the cube the would just slip away. @ekscrypto

Comment: But you just said you wanted the nodes to have a static position and not move with the cube...  You could always have a "blank" node hosting the cube and the falling nodes and move that blank node when you need to move both the cube and the nodes, move only the cube when you want the falling nodes to stay in the same position